# Software that works like Google Chrome's "view page source"

Tags: website-design, html, css, software

I've only been using Google Chrome "CTRL+U" Tools to check my web design's responsiveness and edit styles or elements, however it started to get so freaking laggy which slows me down tremendously.

Is there any software that has similar features?

**Here are the specific features of a software I'm looking for:**

- Device emulation (where I can **toggle resolutions**, **drag-adjustable width**, and **custom width/height** input similar to Google Chrome's Tool)
- Ability to view & edit **page styles (CSS)** of the current visited page.
- Ability to view & edit **page source / elements (HTML)** of the current visited page.
- If possible, with **console logs** similar to Chrome's where I can check for **js/jquery errors & other stuffs**.
- Should work on **locally hosted** websites.

Comment: I would vote to close this question as it is more about software recommendations (https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about user experience.

Answer (score 1):

Do you talk about dev tools on browser? This is shared feature for most of the browsers (safari, chrome, mozilla, edge). My personal favourite is mozilla's dev tools but they all are very similar.

Comment: Yes the devtools. My issue with the browsers one are they're laggy as hell. I always used them for long but it started to get really really laggy lately so im trying to find if there's a software that can do the same.

Comment: @Amenadiel They are not laggy in themselves... Unless you install a million extensions in the browser. Otherwise I suggest your device may need a refresh. I use these tools all the time as well and they don't just automatically get laggy. If you do want to use another professional tool, the closest one I can think of is Adobe Dreamweaver.